# Which is the best media container?

Tags: java, encoding, flv, mp4, mpeg

I'm creating a live streaming app, but I have an issue on which media container is best to choose.

So far I tried ScreenCodec1 and ScreenCodec2, but those are really heavy for a live stream, and the latency is horrible.

Can you suggest a media container that is lightweight? Which is better:

- mp4
- flv
- mpg

Any suggestions on how to encode this with Java from a set of `BufferedImages` will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xuggler can help you with the encoding side of things, see [this page](http://wiki.xuggle.com/Encoding_Video_from_a_sequence_of_Images). As for what format you want to use, that's up to you - it depends on the context and situation. FLV is probably the most widely supported, if that's an important consideration.

Comment: thanks berry, I've tried xuggler but the issue with it is that I can't implement it on a webstart app scince it uses native calls. Do you know of any other written in pure java? multiplataform is important

thank you very much

Comment: Unfortunately the answer is no - there's no pure Java, cross platform solution that I know of for encoding and decoding various video formats. And believe me, I've looked long and hard. It all comes down to native code :-(